# How to convert one DateTime format to another?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have one object `{System.DateTime}`  value is  `{5/17/2010 12:00:00 AM}`.
I want to convert this datetime format to `"d-MMM-yyyy"`,

```
string msStartDt="5/17/2010 12:00:00 AM";    
DateTime.ParseExact(msStartDt, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("d-MMM-yyyy");
```

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

second parameter of ParseExac() method is a format specifier that defines the required format of `msSartDt`.

If I change `{5/17/2010 12:00:00 AM}` to `{17-Dec-2010 12:00:00 AM}` we need to change 2nd parameter of `DateTime.ParseExact()`

My question is how we can find programatically the format of `msStartDt` so we can put in second parameter of `DateTime.ParseExact()` method.

Comment: You're asking two different questions here. You start by saying that you *have* a `DateTime` value - but then you present code that tries to *obtain* a `DateTime` value. Those aren't the same thing. It sounds like you should change your question to "I have a string with the value "5/17/2010 12:00:00 AM". I want to parse this and then format it in a different format."

Comment: your right but the parseexact() require string,so thats why i converted this object into string.

Comment: But if you already *had* a `DateTime` value, you wouldn't need to convert it into a string in order to parse it, would you? It's really unclear whether you've genuinely started off with a string, or whether you really *do* have a `DateTime` value and you've called `ToString()` on it and then want to parse the result, for no obvious reason.

Comment: y,I have a DateTime value and i convert into string

Comment: So why involve parsing at all, if you started with a DateTime?

Comment: i retrive this datetime object from database and want to show in other format

Comment: So just call ToString with the format you want. You don't have to format, parse then reformat.

Comment: "how we can find programatically the format of `msStartDt`" - in general, you can't. Ask someone what month of the year `12/06/2015` is and you'll get drastically different answers from someone in the UK vs someone in the US. Some date formats are inherently ambiguous. There's no way to inspect the string and to *know* what value was intended.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

- [`M` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#M_Specifier) instead of [`MM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MM_Specifier) since single digit numbers don't have leading zero
- [`hh` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) instead of [`HH` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier) since you are using [12-hour format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)
- [`tt` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ttSpecifier) for AM/PM designators

```
string msStartDt = "5/17/2010 12:00:00 AM";    
var str = DateTime.ParseExact(msStartDt, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("d-MMM-yyyy");
```

On the other hand, your question is vauge. You said *I have one object DateTime value is 5/17/2010 12:00:00 AM* but you have a `string` in your code as it.

If you have already a `DateTime`, you just need to format it with `ToString` method. You don't need parsing *at all*.

```
DateTime dt = ...
var str = dt.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> My question is how we can find programatically the format of msStartDt
>   so we can put in second parameter of DateTime.ParseExact() method.

It is not possible.

Think about you have a string like `01/02/2015`. What is the *proper* format of this string? It is 1st February or 2nd January? Is it `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`? It is totally ambiguous as you can see. If you have a `string` formatted, you *have to* know it's proper format to parse a `DateTime`.

Comment: Nice suite Soner! +1 :D

Comment: @dotctor It wasn't fit perfect but I work _really_ hard to get it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `AM/PM` in your string format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(msStartDt, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

also you need to change from `HH` to `hh` because `HH` is for 24h dates

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) you have all datetime fromat constants.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(msStartDt, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

When we use the `ParseExact` the format of the string we parse must be exactly the same with the string. In your case you had omitted the AM/PM designator. Furthermore you need to correct the months and hours. For futher information, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the correct parse format

```
DateTime.ParseExact(msStartDt, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("d-MMM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, convert your specified date from String to DateTime, then convert to another date format:

```
string dateString;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
dateString = "05/17/2010 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString, provider);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"));
```

See other date time formats in the following link: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Your output should be like the follow screenshot:
[image]